# Loading method parameters from file

Tags: python, parameters, metaprogramming, keyword-argument

Assume I have a python function that takes a few parameters:

```
def my_function(a, b, c=1):
    print a, b, c
```

This function is part of a bigger pipeline, that has a lot of parameters.
I often want to call this pipeline with different parameters, so I designed a config file format and a parser to read it.
Some of these parameters need to be passed to different functions.

So I redesign the function to be able to take something from the file (I am skipping error checking and the like here for brevity):

```
def my_function(c=1, **kwargs):
    config = load_config(kwargs.pop(["config_file"]))
    # config is now {'a': 10, 'b': 5}
    config['c'] = c
    # config is now {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'c': 1}
    print config['a'], config['b'], config['c']
```

I can now pass in parameters via code and via the config file.
However, I can not enforce that a given parameter is present in `kwargs`, without having to provide a full list of required parameters and checking if they are all there.

Now the problem with this is that nobody really knows what kind of parameters `my_function` would need without looking at the code.

What I want is the following:

```
def my_function(a, b, c=1, **kwargs):
    config = load_config(kwargs.pop(["config_file"]))
    # config is now {'a': 10, 'b': 5}
    config['c'] = c
    # config is now {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'c': 1}
    print config['a'], config['b'], config['c']
```

However, this is not possible, since I now already NEED to pass `a` and `b` via code, or otherwise I will get a TypeError:

```
my_function(config_file="~/config.yaml")
TypeError: my_function() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Of course, I could specify default values for every parameter, but in some cases that just does not make sense. I want to enforce that this parameter is passed to the function.
So ideally, I want to specify my function as usual with and without default values, and a `**kwargs` in the end. Then I parse the config file, which was passed to the function via those `**kwargs`. I replace every missing parameter with its counterpart from the file and throw an error if THEN there is a parameter that does not have a default value is missing.

How can I achieve that? Is it possible? I'm not opposed to some meta-programming (or another totally different approach to handle this problem).

Comment: Have you tried using a `try` and `except` method so that a failed input can be managed? That would detect a failure in any of the arguments. If you need a different response to different failures then a couple of `if` tests on the inputs would let you choose how to react to failure in each argument before the function is called

Comment: Does not work because I'd need to try/except around the method call, I can't catch it inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You can only easily do this for the kwargs because they're named. Something like this should work:

```
vargs = (1,2,3)
kwargs = {"c": 4, "d": 5}

config_kwargs = load_config("things.config")
kwargs.update(config_kwargs)  # merge the kwargs from the config file over the defaults

my_function(*vargs, **kwargs)   # apply the args to the function
```